# Iterate over array of strings from helper in (express-)handlebars template with {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, express-handlebars

I'm trying to iterate over an array of strings in a handlebars template with [builtin helper '{{#each}}'](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration).
But it doesn't work.

**Simplified example:**

A custom helper function which returns an array of strings:

```
helpers: {
  arr: function () {
    return ['foo', 'bar'];
  }
}
```

The Template in which to access the helper:

```
{{#each arr}}
  {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{else}}
  default
{{/each}}
```

But this always prints the else case.
When directly accessing the helper (without #each) it results as expected:

```
{{arr}} // prints => foo,bar
```

I somewhere read that #each needs a object to work with. I couldn't find anything about this in context of a helper in the docs - nevertheless I tried to wrap the returning array in an object in several ways. But I wasn't able to make it work.

So, how to properly access an array of strings (which comes from a helper) within a handlebars template?

Comment: If you're doing this for testing purposes or as a playground, simply don't have a helper return an array. Helper is supposed to be applied to a value, it's not meant to return an array that you iterate. Is there a reason why your helper returns an array, except for testing purposes? Is there going to be a case where you'll actually use a helper that gives you arrays that you iterate?

Comment: I'm new to handlebars. I'm using [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) in a node app. My understanding was that one use-case of helpers is to pass information (e.g. an array) from server to client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Handlebars documentation on [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) states the following:

> Handlebars offers support for subexpressions, which allows you to invoke multiple helpers within a single mustache, and pass in the results of inner helper invocations as arguments to outer helpers. *Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses*. [emphasis added]

What this means is that we need to tell Handlebars that `arr` is *not* a property to be looked-up on the context object, but a helper to be invoked, and that we do that by wrapping the inner helper in parentheses:

```
{{#each (arr)}}
```

With that said, I would agree with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527819/iterate-over-array-of-strings-from-helper-in-express-handlebars-template-with#comment80010587_46527819) by Mjh, that stated that this is *not* the correct use of a helper. Your data should be passed directly to your template function for interpolation. The purpose of a helper is to modify some data or to perform some logic on it. A helper function that has no parameters is a pretty pungent code-smell.